# Android studio build error on ubuntu install

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-14.10

i have recently installed android studio on my newly installed OS ubuntu 14.10, i installed the main android studio file in my documents folder, and then downloaded and installed the sdk build tools file in the documents folder aswell and linked the two via the sdk in android studio, i also downloaded all the latest apis and build tools, however when i build my first app

```
Error:Error: Cannot run program "/home/user/Documents/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
```

and

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

> /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Epic3/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/user/Documents/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Does the directory exist?

Comment: yes, the aapt file exists in the 21.1.1 folder, so im guessing its an issue with the sdk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I faced the same problem and in my case is that im running Ubuntu 64 version. I solved that running the following command line:

```
apt-get install -qq -y libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libz1:i386
```